# ##[warning]'git config --get remote.origin.url' failed with exit code: 1, output: '' - Azure Devops CI/CD Pipeline Permission Issue

Tags: git, next.js, azure-devops, yaml, cicd

I get these errors whenever i tried running my pipelines on my created agent ,lets say agent_test.

When I run pipelines for first time it works and if retried to run after that, same issues occur.

```
##[warning]'git config --get remote.origin.url' failed with exit code: 1, output: ''
##[error]One or several exceptions have been occurred.
##[error]System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/ubuntu/projectfile/myagent/_work/1/s/.next/cache/images/Nn1+Lvq9fpQugwxAHfYtWM8Fp0OWmIqb38i9HtcZ67Q=/60.1698820786123.R-Lptnv+qGQlQiip-n7JqnPeS4MDNx4NR4C9HBtCcNk=.webp' is denied.
---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Before Build script, it gives error and stop running, the stop process name is "Checkout project-file@development to s"

My YML Script is :

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  name: 'projectfile'
  
stages:      
- stage: SetPermissions
  jobs:
  - job: SetPermissions
    displayName: 'Set Permissions'
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Cleaning the repository..."
        git clean -ff  # Clean the repository to avoid permission issues
        git reset --hard HEAD
        echo "Setting permissions for the working directory..."
        chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        chmod -R u+rw $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        
      displayName: 'Set Permissions'
      continueOnError: true

- stage: BuildAndDeploy
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build'
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Current working directory is: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        echo "Install npm"
        npm install
        pwd       
        echo "Building the project..."
        npm run build
        echo "Installing pm2..."
        npm install pm2
      displayName: 'Npm install and Build'
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        artifact: 'userside_dev_artifact'
      displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
    - script: |
        echo "Deploying the project..."
        pwd

        # Check if PM2 connection is already established
        if ! pm2 list | grep -q "projectfile"; then
          echo "PM2 process not found. Running 'npm run pm2'..."
          npm run pm2
        else
          echo "PM2 process is already running. Skipping 'npm run pm2'."
        fi

        pm2 restart all
        echo "Deployment successful!"
      displayName: 'Deploy'
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

Weird things is, when i use `chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu _work` and `chmod -R u+rw _work`
then pipeline run successfully and again if pipeline tried to run for second times, then it gives same above error. I tried different way, but still this issue has not been resolve. Provide me the solution to fix.

Note that : The above script is for user side which is build in next and same issue arise in admin panel build on react, but the issue doesnt arise in backend which is build in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.
By default azure dont allow root access neither sudo command.so what i did is :

In config.sh, ADD THIS COMMAND

```
export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"
```

Similarly,
In run.sh, add same command using nano editor or any editor:

```
export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"
```

and then we can do,

```
sudo ./config.sh
```

So, by this way we can provide root access to all the directory in azure devops

Article I have wrote, how i fixed the issue: https://medium.com/@sandipdulal/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline-permission-issue-fix-033bfaf4bb8c

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the account(pipeline) doesn't have permission on the file:

> ##[error]System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/ubuntu/projectfile/myagent/_work/1/s/.next/cache/images/Nn1+Lvq9fpQugwxAHfYtWM8Fp0OWmIqb38i9HtcZ67Q=/60.1698820786123.R-Lptnv+qGQlQiip-n7JqnPeS4MDNx4NR4C9HBtCcNk=.webp' is denied.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

It could happen when the file or folder is being used by another process or application, or it's read-only, hidden, encryted.

Probably you can firstly try to define a [workspace clean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace) schema under the job and choose the resources to clean up(eg: all).

```
  - job: myJob
    workspace:
      clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job
```

**If it's unable to clean up** the working directory and the error persists, you could need to check how the `.next/cache/images/N...webapp` generated in your workspace:

Manually delete the files in local agent, run the pipeline and check if it will generate the files.

If not, these files should be generated by other process.

If yes, check your npm build steps. Could add two `chmod -R` commands after the npm build steps, so that it could have the permission for next build.

Comment: still cant solve the issue, first time it works fines after deleting cache and again same error occur at next pipeline run

Comment: yes chmod and chown are already assigned on yml script as shown above which should be executed before build

Comment: @DulalSandip, may i know if you have followed the steps, confirmed where are the files from? If they are generated by the build self, have you add the two commands `chown -R` and `chmod -R` to add the permission before the build complete?

Comment: Not before the build, but at the end of the build. make sure the 1st build can complete.

Comment: yes, i added after build, and run the script
workingDir="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.next/cache"
        echo "find directory path"
         ls -l "$workingDir"
        if [ -d "$workingDir" ]; then
           
           chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu "$workingDir/images"
           chmod -R u+rw "$workingDir/images"
           ls -l "$workingDir/images"
        else
          echo "Directory $workingDir does not exist."
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
but when i did ls -l workingdir, it doesnt give me images directory in logs

Comment: but images directory exists in my ec2,
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  185 Nov  2 11:32 config.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Nov  2 11:34 images
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Nov  2 11:32 swc
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Nov  2 11:33 webpack
and images directory gets root access automatically, but in pipeline logs, it couldnt found images directory.so this is the problem i faced when i did after build

Comment: @DulalSandip, please check which account is used to setup the devops agent(`whoami` command in pipeline), if it's not your account, set the agent with your account. It's because if you run the two command manually after build, the pipeline can work. If the issue persists, please edit your ticket statement add related script and screenshot so all SO folks can help to check.

Comment: i did whoami, it says ubuntu which is right. but earlier i told, images directory is not generated in pipeline logs and when i see in ec2, there is images directory which has root access.so, i am unable to change the root to ubuntu access in pipeline script, because images directory doesnt appear in pipeline logs execution.

Comment: @DulalSandip, thanks for clarification. If the image directory are not generated by the pipeline, the error will report as pipeline doesn't have access to. Does this image directory exist in your DevOps repo too? The cache files could be not mandatory for your build, if so, you can try to remove them from repo, so that check out will not access to the local directory.

Comment: the main problem is, azure agent doesnt support root access, and when i provide ubuntu access to my all directory,its working, in package.json of next js, i have added   "build": "npm run build && mkdir -p images && mv images .next/cache"
then images directory also gets ubuntu access, but as my image is optimized, when users visit the site, the cache image save in this directory and gets root access like image.webp root access, and when dev push the code, pipeline execute and couldnt delete that image says access denied. now i am confuse how to give those newly created image ubuntu access

Comment: @DulalSandip, probably you could consider to change the image directory out of working directory on agent machine. so that when user access, or dev push, won't change the working directory. It could need change your reference to the directory in the code as well.

Comment: I think it wont fix my issue.  let me show my issue that the images gained automatic root access when user visits the website for first time 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-60:~/rennovation_guru_userside_dev/myagent/_work_userside_dev/1/s/.next/cache/images$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  8 11:04 'RmizOLZrJZHiPnIY2URPSRDXb5nPi6YG2bSuYzHkArc='
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  8 11:04 'Z3qR3IxP64YKX67qrHwb9sNbteuTLrm9oc5SPDbY8j8='
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  8 11:04 'jZg4qtGiamBirKh9iHvYES7UHH8IX2oQA3eOcoUWjSs='
whereas i need ubuntu access automatic in cached image

Comment: solved the issue. I wrote the answer below after researching .

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved! Thanks for your solution!